# How to preserve linked tables in Access when copying to different machines

Tags: ms-access

We have a Access DB with 1000+ linked tables and about 200 local tables.
We need this Access DB to reside on the desktops of about 40 users.
The problem is, each time I copy the Access file to a new PC, even though the ODBC connection name is the same for the linked tables, it always asks me to relink all 1000+ tables and I have to click okay 1000+ times.

Is there a way to save the file in such a way that it preserves the linked relationships and the ODBC name so I can easily copy it from machine to machine?

Comment: If you have `Access 365` then you can link tables directly without `ODBC`. That file will work without relink tables. Just copy & paste to other PC's.

Comment: Please add a sample connection string of a linked table. -- I suggest using DSN-less connections.

Answer (score 1):

Use a DSN-less connection and a function to relink (only needed to switch database) all the tables and pass-through queries:

```vb
Public Function AttachSqlServer( _
    ByVal Hostname As String, _
    ByVal Database As String, _
    ByVal Username As String, _
    ByVal Password As String) _
    As Boolean

' Attach all tables linked via ODBC to SQL Server or Azure SQL.
' 2016-04-24. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

    Const cstrDbType    As String = "ODBC"
    Const cstrAcPrefix  As String = "dbo_"

    Dim dbs             As DAO.Database
    Dim tdf             As DAO.TableDef
    Dim qdf             As DAO.QueryDef
    
    Dim strConnect      As String
    Dim strName         As String
    
    On Error GoTo Err_AttachSqlServer
    
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    strConnect = ConnectionString(Hostname, Database, Username, Password)
    
    For Each tdf In dbs.TableDefs
        strName = tdf.Name
        If Asc(strName) <> Asc("~") Then
            If InStr(tdf.Connect, cstrDbType) = 1 Then
                If Left(strName, Len(cstrAcPrefix)) = cstrAcPrefix Then
                    tdf.Name = Mid(strName, Len(cstrAcPrefix) + 1)
                End If
                tdf.Connect = strConnect
                tdf.RefreshLink
                Debug.Print Timer, tdf.Name, tdf.SourceTableName, tdf.Connect
                DoEvents
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    For Each qdf In dbs.QueryDefs
        If qdf.Connect <> "" Then
            Debug.Print Timer, qdf.Name, qdf.Type, qdf.Connect
            qdf.Connect = strConnect
        End If
    Next
    Debug.Print "Done!"
    
    AttachSqlServer = True
    
Exit_AttachSqlServer:
    Set tdf = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
    Exit Function
    
Err_AttachSqlServer:
    Call ErrorMox
    Resume Exit_AttachSqlServer
    
End Function



Public Function ConnectionString( _
    ByVal Hostname As String, _
    ByVal Database As String, _
    ByVal Username As String, _
    ByVal Password As String, _
    Optional ByVal AdoStyle As Boolean) _
    As String

' Create ODBC or ADO connection string from its variable elements.
' 2021-06-15. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

    Const AzureDomain   As String = ".windows.net"
    Const OdbcPrefix    As String = "ODBC;"
    Const OdbcConnect   As String = _
        "DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 11.0;" & _
        "Description=Cactus TimeSag og Finans;" & _
        "APP=Microsoft® Access;" & _
        "SERVER={0};" & _
        "DATABASE={1};" & _
        "UID={2};" & _
        "PWD={3};" & _
        "Trusted_Connection={4};"
        
    Dim FullConnect     As String
    
    If Right(Hostname, Len(AzureDomain)) = AzureDomain Then
        ' Azure SQL connection.
        ' Append servername to username.
        Username = Username & "@" & Split(Hostname)(0)
    End If
    If Not AdoStyle Then
        FullConnect = OdbcPrefix
    End If
    FullConnect = FullConnect & OdbcConnect
    FullConnect = Replace(FullConnect, "{0}", Hostname)
    FullConnect = Replace(FullConnect, "{1}", Database)
    FullConnect = Replace(FullConnect, "{2}", Username)
    FullConnect = Replace(FullConnect, "{3}", Password)
    FullConnect = Replace(FullConnect, "{4}", IIf(Username & Password = "", "Yes", "No"))
    
    ConnectionString = FullConnect

End Function
```

Also, study my article: [Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application with one click](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33417/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-with-one-click.html?preview=X8LitkMCd/Y%3D)